# Why does OSX no longer allow to save screenshots in the clipboard?

Tags: macos, big-sur, screen-capture

Since recently the shortcut <kbd>CMD</kbd> +  <kbd>SHFT</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>  does no loger create a screenshot in the clipboard but puts it into the downloads folder. I could not figure out how to change that. Did the recent update to 11.4 bring this "improvement" or is a setting wrong?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by user error and therefore won't be helpful to future readers.

Comment: @jballin We have a lot of questions here which basically describe user errors. If it happens to one user it may happen to others as well, so this shouldn't be a reason to close questions.

Comment: As I mentioned before, I do not think it is a user error. This worked for me for years now and suddenly stopped working. It might have been a custom config I did  which I can not remember anymore, fact is that things have changed after the update.

Comment: Maybe we can edit the question to be more general to keyboard shortcuts no longer working after an update?

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Cmd-Shift-4</kbd> saves a screenshot to file, <kbd>Cmd-Ctrl-Shift-4</kbd> puts it into the clipboard. This has been the default for ages, it did not change with macOS 11.4.

Comment: Strange, I am 100% sure that it was CMD-Shift-4 on my mac, but is now no longer. I am using this daily now for several years.

Comment: You can change it in keyboard prefs > shortcuts > screenshots - & you must have done this at some time in the past. the defaults are as the answer.